# Check if another page contains element before using .load() method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery's [.load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to dynamically change page content. I'd like to perform a check to see if the content I'm trying to load actually exists. Here's an example I've taken from the jQuery documentation:

```
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" );
```

How can I check to see if `/resources/load.html` actually contains a `#projects li`?

I'm aware we can get a response from the Ajax request...

```
 $( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/fail.html", function (response,status,xhr) {
    if(status=='error') {
        alert('error');
    }
}
```

...but this only seems to work if the target file doesn't exist.

Help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a workaround using generic AJAX rather than `load()`.

```
$.get('some/url').done(function(html) {
    if (!$(html).find('some/selector').length) return; //if element not found, forget it
    $('some/container').html(html); //if is found, dump the HTML in the container
});
```

Comment: I was having difficulty replacing just a particular section of the HTML on the page with this method. However I've used it to check if the element is found at all, which does the job when combined with `load()`. So thanks a lot!

Comment: The only problem with that approach, if I've understood correctly, is you'll be firing two AJAX requests for the content - the first, from my code, and the second via `load()`. Good luck.